# Is it possible to pass in the price of the token as a parameter?

Tags: solidity

Lets say I want a token which has a dynamic emmission rate based on the price of the token on an exchange like uniswap. Is this possible and how would I go about doing that. Is it possible to get this information from the blockchain itself or do I need to use an api that keeps track of the price?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Uniswap [on-chain oracle](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/core-concepts/oracles/).

Basically, when someone calls your contract to mint tokens, your contract uses the Uniswap oracle to check the price of the token, then calculate the minting rate or whatever you want to calculate based on that price.